On Cal.com Self-Hosted: Paid Booking Confirmation Email Not Received and Booking Status Not Updated
I am using a self-hosted instance of Cal.com running on Vercel. The system works perfectly for free bookings, where I can book, update, and reschedule events, and I receive the confirmation email without any issues.
However, I am experiencing problems with paid bookings. Here is what happens:
I arrive at the payment page.
I enter all the necessary payment information.
I am redirected to the confirmation page.
Despite this, I encounter two major issues:
I do not receive the confirmation email.
The booking status is not marked as "paid" in the database.
This issue does not occur with free bookings, which makes me think it might be related to the payment process or configuration.
Additional Information:
Cal.com version: 817a3dec
Hosting platform: Vercel
Payment provider: With Stripe
Questions:
What could be causing the confirmation email to not be sent for paid bookings?
Why is the booking status not updated to "paid" in Cal.com?
Are there any specific logs or settings I should check to diagnose this issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Checked the email settings to ensure they are correctly configured.
Verified that the payment integration is correctly set up and processes payments successfully.
Reviewed the Cal.com documentation for any additional steps or configurations needed for paid bookings.
Checked my spam/junk folders to ensure the emails are not being filtered out.
Compared the settings for free and paid event types to look for discrepancies.
Install Sendgrid and Twilio for workflows
